# Laravel Valet hosted sites return 'Site can't be reached' in Chrome

Tags: laravel, google-chrome, laravel-valet

So I have been using Laravel's Valet feature for my Laravel project for a few weeks no without any problems.

I have updated my Mac OS today and found that my project cannot be reached within Chrome, whats weird is the problem only occurs in Chrome. I can access the site fine in Safari.

I get the follow error on Chrome:

> This site can’t be reached myproject.app refused to connect.

The site isn't using SSL so I dont think this is a SSL certificate issue as some people have suggested in other posts I have seen.
I have already checked and all Brew services are running.

Any ideas what this could be?

Comment: Are you using Chrome 63 and a .dev tld?

Comment: I am using `Version 63.0.3239.108` but using .app tlds

Answer (score 0):

try change your domain from app to test

```
valet domain test
```

Comment: I have tried changing to something else, it still doesnt work in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Probs a little late on this and you probably found a solution but for others searching:

Little new thing with chrome now, it always wants SSL and is mean about .dev for some reason.

So..

a. Use .test preferably (i see you're already using .app which should work fine!)

b. Use SSL. Simply go to the directory of your application in terminal and enter `valet secure` to make it use SSL.

c. Check you're not running a proxy or VPN in chrome (spend 2h searching before realising my nordvpn chrome extension automatically connected... thats how I found your question ^^')

otherwise try `ps aux | grep` in terminal to check if your DNS is working. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a VPN? I had the same problem with ExpreeVPN and I solved it by disabling Only use ExpressVPN DNS servers while connected from Advanced settings. The solution was posted here: https://github.com/laravel/valet/issues/527